# Transforming Kernel Density Estimator for non-negative observations

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transformation, kernel-density

I am modelling the distribution of repair costs with the Kernel Density Estimator of the scikit learn package in Python. I have created the density function fitted to my observations, but when taking a random sample from this distribution negative values occur. Since the observations regard costs, which are always positive, sample values should be non-negative.

I have read that with transformation of the data this result can be reached. These sources use log transformation to truncate the distribution at 0 ([Log-transform kernel density estimation of income distribution](http://web5.uottawa.ca/ssms/vfs/.horde/eventmgr/001774_001412597609_Flachaire.pdf), [Kernel Density Estimation for Random Variables with Bounded Support — The Transformation Trick](http://thirdorderscientist.org/homoclinic-orbit/2013/10/24/kernel-density-estimation-for-random-variables-with-bounded-support-mdash-the-transformation-trick) ). The problem is that I don't know how to use this log transformation of my observations in combination with the scikit learn Kernal Density function.

The code for the KDE without tranformation is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import math as math

'Dataframe with costs'
x = costs

maxVal = x.max()
minVal = x.min()
upperBound = math.ceil(maxVal/1000)*1000

x_grid = np.linspace(0, upperBound, 1000)

'Create pdf with Kernel Density'
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=612).fit(x_grid[:, np.newaxis])
log_pdf = kde.score_samples(x_grid[:, np.newaxis])
pdf=np.exp(log_pdf)
```

My code including transformation:

```
'Log tranformation and creation of pdf'

x_pseudo = x.apply(np.log)

kde_psuedo = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=612).fit(x_pseudo[:, np.newaxis])
log_pdf_pseudo = kde_psuedo.score_samples(x_pseudo[:, np.newaxis])
pdf_pseudo=np.exp(log_pdf_pseudo)

x_grid_log = np.linspace(minVal, maxVal, 1000)

density = np.zeros(len(x_grid_log))

for i in range(len(x_grid_log)):
    xx=x_grid_log[i]
    density[i]=pdf_pseudo[xx.apply(np.log)/xx]

output = list(x=x_grid_log, y=density)
```

This code is based on the example in source [2](http://thirdorderscientist.org/homoclinic-orbit/2013/10/24/kernel-density-estimation-for-random-variables-with-bounded-support-mdash-the-transformation-trick), that is made in R. I know the code is wrong, but I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Division by xx needs to happen outside the pdf_pseudo per equation 5 in the U Ottawa paper you referenced.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Are you trying to get the distribution of the original (non-log transformed) data under the constraint that costs can only be positive? Or would it be ok to have a distribution of the log costs? What exactly is going wrong in your code? Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: It is now deleted.